# JS code loading before HTML and causing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript

I'm on a CMS where I can't change the JS position. By default of the CMS, JS code has to be placed on top of the page:

```js
document.getElementById("custom_map_0_marker_tolerance").value = "1";
```

This HTML code is placed below the JS code and hence it's not loading and I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null.

```html
<input type="text" class="fcfield_textval inlineval addrint_marker_tolerance" id="custom_map_0_marker_tolerance" name="custom[map][0][marker_tolerance]" value="50" size="7" maxlength="7">
```

I can't edit the HTML code but I can add/edit JS codes. How can I fix this so that the value shows **1** instead of **50**?

Comment: As tagged [tag:jquery] use [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) - if you don't want jquery (then A: don't tag jquery...) then you can use http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener on the document:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',(LoadEvt)=>{
   window.document.getElementById("custom_map_0_marker_tolerance").value = "1";
})
```

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you. Will accept it once it's allowed in 6 minutes.